# CLLocationManager and iBeacons: is requestState(for: region) necessary?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon

I'm trying to build an iBeacons app with Swift 4 in iOS 10. Many sources recommend the following:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
manager.requestState(for: region)
}
```

to handle the case when the app starts inside a beacon region. However, this approach seems to cause side effects and timing errors in some situations.

Now, I found this StackOverflow article [Understanding iBeacons in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010742/understanding-ibeacons-in-ios-diddeterminestate-and-didenterregion-events) that states, "didDetermineState is only called automatically when you start monitoring".

Sure enough, if I leave out the call to `requestState(for: region)`, and just call `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)`everything works perfectly!

Can anyone confirm that this is indeed the case? If I call `startMonitoring` then there is no need for `requestState`?

Note: I set `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay` to `true` before I start monitoring. I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not calling `locationManager.requestState(for: region)` is necessary all depends on your use case.

The callback `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion)` will be called automatically in the following cases:

1. When you first start monitoring.
2. For all region state changes.  This includes .outside -> .inside, .inside -> .outside as well as transitions to and from .unknown
3. Whenever the display is illuminated (only if you set your monitored `BeaconRegion` `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=true`)

So if these cases are sufficient for you, then **you don't need to request additional callbacks**.  This is generally true.

There are some rare use cases, however, where explicitly requesting a new callback is helpful.   Perhaps your app presents a new View Controller and then wants to visually show the user the region state.   It is convenient to be able to call `requestState` when the view loads, and then update the display when the callback is made.

Specific side effects and **problems caused by extra callbacks really depend on what you put inside the callback.** If you start or stop monitoring in these callbacks, it's very easy to create feedback loops that cause problems.